# Private Channel not working in Laravel

Tags: laravel, pusher

In my ChatEvent i called function

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new Channel('chat');
}
```

And in `app.js` i have Echo.

```
Echo.channel('chat')
        .listen('ChatEvent', (e) => {
            this.chat.message.push(e.message);
            console.log(e);
    })
```

It works pretty well. But, when i change `Channel` to `PrivateChannel` in `function broadcastOn()` and in `app.js` I change

```
Echo.private('chat')
        .listen('ChatEvent', (e) => {
            this.chat.message.push(e.message);
            console.log(e);
    })
```

I have error `POST broadcasting/auth 403 (Forbidden)` @@ And 
Can I use Channel instead of PrivateChannel?

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned in document you have to define the authorization rule for this private channel

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting#authorizing-channels

edit your routes/channels.php file

```
Broadcast::channel('chat', function ($user) {
    return true; //for public access
    // or
    return $user->can('chat'); //using gate
});
```

else use the channel for public access

Comment: Yup, i was change channel.php But Error 403 still not lost

Answer (score 1):

When you use Private or PresenceChannel, Fix Error 403 /broadcasting/auth with Laravel version > 5.3 & Pusher, you need change your code in **resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js** with

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'your key',
    cluster: 'your cluster',
    encrypted: true,
    auth: {
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + YourTokenLogin
        },
    },
});
```

And in **app/Providers/BroadcastServiceProvider.php** change by

```
Broadcast::routes()
```

with

```
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:api']]);
```

or

```
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth']]); //if you use JWT
```

it worked for me, and hope it help you.

Comment: But what is `YourTokenLogin`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

in Chat event add

```
public function broadcastAs()
{
    return 'new.chat';
}
```

in your javascript file

```
Echo.channel('chat')
        .listen('.new.chat', (e) => {
            console.log(e);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

if use api

```
window.Echo.connector.options.auth.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${user.api_token}`;
```

if use *session auth* without top code